# prove that the function $L: l_\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow l_\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is well defined with the following norm.

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove that the function $L: l_\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow l_\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is well defined with norm $||L|| = \frac{|\alpha \beta|}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$ where $-1<\alpha,\beta<1$.

The function is defined component-wise for $k \geq 1$ as:

$L(\{\psi_n\})_k = \sum_{j \geq 1} \alpha^k \beta^j \psi_j$.

So what i thought is that i first prove that that each COMPONENT is in $l_\mathbb{R}^{2}$:

$\sum_{j \geq 1} \alpha^k \beta^j \psi_j \leq \sum_{j \geq 1} |\psi_j| \leq \sum_{j \geq 1} |\psi_j|^2$ if $\psi_j \geq 1$

I am not sure how to prove for all $\psi_j$.

So for the second part I think I need to prove that:

$\sum_{k \geq 1} |\sum_{j \geq 1} \alpha^k \beta^j \psi_j|^2 < \infty$:

$\sum_{k \geq 1} |\sum_{j \geq 1} \alpha^k \beta^j \psi_j|^2 \leq \sum_{k \geq 1} \left(\sum_{j \geq 1} |\alpha^{k} \beta^{j} \psi_j|\right)^2$

And here i get stuck, any hints that can help me out?

Kees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the definition of $L$ is 
\begin{align*}
\left(L\xi\right)_{k} & =\alpha^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\beta^{j}\xi_{j},\quad\xi=\left(\xi_{j}\right)\in l^{2}.
\end{align*}
It follows that 
\begin{align*}
\left|\left(L\xi\right)_{k}\right| & \leq\left|\alpha\right|^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left|\beta^{j}\xi_{j}\right|\leq\left|\alpha\right|^{k}\frac{\left|\beta\right|}{\sqrt{1-\beta^{2}}}\left\Vert \xi\right\Vert \quad(\text{Cauchy-Schwarz})
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\left\Vert L\xi\right\Vert  & \leq\frac{\left|\alpha\beta\right|}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^{2}}\sqrt{1-\beta^{2}}}\left\Vert \xi\right\Vert ,\quad\forall\xi\in l^{2}.
\end{align*}
But ``$=$'' is obtained at $\xi=\left(\xi_{j}\right)\in l^{2}$
s.t. $\xi_{j}:=\beta^{j}$, so $\left\Vert L\right\Vert $ is as claimed.

So take $\xi$ s.t. $\xi_{j}=\beta^{j}=j^{th}$ power of $\beta$, then
\begin{align*}
\left\Vert \xi\right\Vert  & =\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\beta^{2j}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\left|\beta\right|}{\sqrt{1-\beta^{2}}},
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\left(L\xi\right)_{k} & =\alpha^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\beta^{j}\xi_{j}=\alpha^{k}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\beta^{2j}=\alpha^{k}\frac{\beta^{2}}{1-\beta^{2}}.
\end{align*}
Thus, 
\begin{align*}
\left\Vert L\xi\right\Vert  & =\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\alpha^{2k}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\beta^{2}}{1-\beta^{2}}\\
 & =\frac{\left|\alpha\beta\right|}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^{2}}\sqrt{1-\beta^{2}}}\cdot\frac{\left|\beta\right|}{\sqrt{1-\beta^{2}}}=\frac{\left|\alpha\beta\right|}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^{2}}\sqrt{1-\beta^{2}}}\left\Vert \xi\right\Vert .
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your response :), i had a few questions though:

Comment: can you explain the last remark with the =, i dont understand why you can conclude that by filling in the variable in the function?

Comment: Sure, I added a bit more in the above post.